# How to get an Angular Hello World app under 10KB?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

Looking at some videos of Ng Conf 2018 (for example: https://youtu.be/dIxknqPOWms?t=2781) and other links around the internet it is stated that the size of a Hello World Angular application, on version 6, is lower than 10kb. Nevertheless, I can't get even closer to this.

I've done the following:

1. Created a fresh app using angular cli (**ng new** project_name)
2. Cleared the entire app.component.html file
3. Removed the title property from app.component.ts
4. Built it using angular cli (**ng build --prod**)

And even using what I understand to be the most basic possible angular app, I still get the following results (far bigger than 10KB):

```
chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.34c57ab7888ec1573f9c.css (styles) 0 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.2f4a59095805af02bd79.js (polyfills) 59.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} main.d93604449a57684c818d.js (main) 169 kB [initial] [rendered]
```

I've did a lot of research on stack overflow, github, blogs and angular related sites, and can't find a clue on that.

What am I missing? How to get this < 10KB app?

Comment: They are using the new ivy renderer.

Comment: its not for this version , they were talking about the new renderer engine ivy that will make it less than 10 kb

Comment: Minimize js and css

Comment: Seems that < 10KB will happen only with Ivy, but still, current Hello World size should be smaller (around 36KB) as shown here: https://youtu.be/jnp_ny4SOQE?t=2273

Comment: @GCSDC there are a lot of details here. 36kb is without zone.js and is gzipped. They should have mentioned that

Answer (score 0):

The demo which you are talking about is using Ivy Renderer. It's still work in progress. You can enable it to test by following instructions mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21706)

Comment: I've added , **"angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": true }** to **ts.config.json** but still getting the same results as before when running **ng build --prod**. Also not sure if Ivy is being used or not.